# Going back to previous page, maintaining data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a search page, where once I input some parameters, I get search results back. Some of the values have links in the results, when I click on them it will route me to another page. I have a back button on the new page where if I click it, I want it to go back to the previous results page with the search results still present.

Is there a way to do so in Angular cli?

Comment: You need to implement RouteReuseStrategy https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy

Comment: @DavidAguirre thanks for the suggestion! I find that once I go back to the page the results are still there, but if I click on another link on the page, the link takes me to the first link I clicked the first time, so the memory did not refresh. Is there anyway to solve that?

Comment: Can you post code? It sounds like you are not subscribed to param changes, or you may need to specify which routes use the RouteReuseStrategy.